# JAVA - GPS RECEPTOR sending strange/encoded frames in console

Tags: java, com, gps, encode, nmea

I have a GPS receptor, which send me NMEA frames.
My code retrieve these ones, but in a really strange form :

[image]

I am using [PuTTY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY) to see the NMEA frames received by my receptor, and there is no problem.

[image]

**EDIT - Here is the code I am using :**

```
public class GPSFrame extends Observable implements Runnable
{
    static Thread myThread=null;
    static BufferedReader br;
    static BufferedWriter wr;
    static PrintWriter out;
    static InputStreamReader isr;
    static OutputStreamWriter osw;
    static java.io.RandomAccessFile port; 


    /**  CONSTRUCTOR **/
    public  GPSFrame()
    {    
         myThread=new Thread(this);
    }

    public void start()
    {
        try 
        {
            port=new java.io.RandomAccessFile("COM5","rwd");
            port.writeBytes("\r\n");
            port.writeBytes("c,31,0,0,5\r\n");
            port.writeBytes("T,1000,1\r\n");
        }
        catch (Exception e){ System.out.println("start "+e.toString()); }
        // The thread start automatically run() method
        myThread.start();
    }

/**********************************************************************************************
 *************************** RETRIEVE GPS FRAMES AND SEND TO SERVEUR **************************
 **********************************************************************************************/
    public void run() 
    {
        System.out.println("lecture COM...");
        // INFINIT LOOP - GPSFrame is always listening for the GPS receptor
        for(;;)
        {
            String st = null;
            try 
            {
                st=port.readLine();
                String[]gpsframe=st.split(",");

                /* IMPORTANT - DON'T FORGET SETCHANGED() or GPSFrame'll never
                 * notify UPDATE() ServerBoard method - We'll never see any changes */
                setChanged();
                notifyObservers(st);

            } 
            catch (IOException e){ System.out.println(e.getMessage()); }
            // Show in console
            System.out.println(st);
        }
    }   
}
```

**EDIT :**

**When I first read GPS Frames with** [PuTTY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY) **then launch my application, I can see correct GPS Frames in console. But when I try to read the GPS Frame with my application first, I have encoded Frames.**

I don't know why I can't retrieve the frames in this form.
Can someone guide me to resolve this problem please ?

Thanks to you in advance !

Regards,

Tofuw

Comment: Please add your code to the question.

Comment: @aphex sorry, I've just added my code.

Comment: I think you are not reading from the com port properly... Try with readUTF8() or check out this example from oracle: https://blogs.oracle.com/hinkmond/entry/rpi_and_java_embedded_gpio8

Comment: Check the baud rate, sure the GPS sends at  that rate?

Comment: @AlexWien, I think the problem is not there, and the baud rate is 1000ms. Otherwise, when I first read GPS Frame with PuTTY, then launch my application, I can retrieve correctly the GPS Frame.

Comment: @aphex, I've tried to use readUTF(), but it send me `null null null null null... ` for each frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution for my problem ! :D

My code is a little problematic because I used RandomAccessFile to read on my COM Port. With this method I can read the frame sended by the receptor, but not properly. The solved it, I have to **`CONFIGURE the COM PORT`**, which **is not possible with RandomAccessFile**.

I did a configuration test :

- With DATABITS_5 or DATABITS_6, I received these sort of frame :

  > $%*()
  >   :2    ")1"*2
- But with DATABITS_7 or DATABITS_8, I received good frame :

  > $GPRMC,100409.000,A,4858.018,N,00150.999,E,0.0,0.0,201213,0.0,W*70
  >   $GPGGA,100409.000,4858.01754,N,00150.99913,E,1,15,0.7,034.93,M,47.2,M,,*66

I think by default, Databits or configured with 5 or 6. It depends. That is why it is better configure up ourselves the Port.

The way (or one of the way ?) to configure the COM Port, is to use **SerialPort**.

**Here is a solution** which is really helpfull *(in this example we are reading data with an event mode, but you can use the flow mode - please see the 2nd links below for it)* :

```
public class GPScom implements SerialPortEventListener
{
    private String portcom;
    private CommPortIdentifier portid=null; 
    private SerialPort serialport; 
    private BufferedReader fluxgps; // Reading flow port where the GPS is connected

        public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        // Driver initialization
        Win32Driver driver=new Win32Driver();
        driver.initialize();

        GPScom gpscom=new GPScom();
        gpscom.listPort();
    }

    // Scanning all available ports
    public void listPort()
    {
        Enumeration listport=CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
        int typeport;
        String GPSPortCOM;

        while(listport.hasMoreElements())
        {
            portid=(CommPortIdentifier)(CommPortIdentifier)listport.nextElement();
            if(portid.getPortType()==CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL)
            {
                System.out.println("Port Name : "+portid.getName());
                System.out.println("User : "+portid.getCurrentOwner());
                System.out.println("Use ? : "+portid.isCurrentlyOwned());
                System.out.println("Port type : "+portid.getPortType());

                this.ModeEvenement(portid.getName());
            }
        }
    }

    // Initialization of the port
    public void ModeEvenement(String portcom)
    {
        // Retrieve ID Port
        try{portid=CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(portcom);}
        catch(NoSuchPortException e){System.out.println(e);}

        // Open Port
        try{serialport=(SerialPort)portid.open("ModeEvenement",2000);}
        catch(PortInUseException e){System.out.println(e);}

        // Retrieve data flow
        try{fluxgps=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(serialport.getInputStream()));}
        catch(IOException e){System.out.println(e);}

        // Add listener
        try{serialport.addEventListener(this);}
        catch(TooManyListenersException e){System.out.println(e);}

        // Configure Port
        serialport.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
        try{serialport.setSerialPortParams(4800, SerialPort.DATABITS_6, SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);}
        catch(UnsupportedCommOperationException e){System.out.println(e);}

        System.out.println("Port is open, waiting for the reading");
    }

    // Here we are reading 7 frames for test
    public void ReadSerialPort()
    {
        int i=7;
        String reponse=new String();

        try
        {
            System.out.println("i="+i);
            while(i!=0)
            {
                System.out.println("Reading the COM port \n");
                reponse=(String)fluxgps.readLine();
                System.out.println(reponse);
                i--;
                System.out.println("i="+i);
            }           
        }
        catch(IOException e){System.out.println(e);}

        // On ferme le flux de lecture
        try{fluxgps.close();}
        catch(IOException e){System.out.println(e);}

        serialport.close();
    }

    public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event)
    {
        // We are only reading data if available
        switch(event.getEventType())
        {
            case SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE:
                this.ReadSerialPort(); // Launching the reading if data are available
                break;
            default:
                break; // Else, do nothing
        }
    }   
}
```

This is where I found this solution (/!\ French sites :D ):

- [Read COM Port](http://www.commentcamarche.net/forum/affich-2911334-java-api-javax-comm-lire-port-com)
- [How to use javax.comm for serial port](http://christophej.developpez.com/tutoriel/java/javacomm/#L2.3.3)

I hope it will help you if you encounter the same problem as me

Have a nice day !!!

Tofuw

PS : Thanks to Aphex and AlexWien who helped me

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comment you are not reading from the COM port correctly. I found a library that might help you to figure out how to read from the com port. The code is pretty old, but I thinks it is still helpful:
http://javanmea.sourceforge.net/

Checkout these classes: [NMEAReader](http://javanmea.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/javanmea/javanmea/src/ocss/nmea/api/NMEAReader.java?view=markup) and [CustomReader](http://javanmea.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/javanmea/javanmea/src/ui/sampleclient/CustomReader.java?view=markup).

There is also a similar c++ thread that might be helpful. [Receive NMEA0183 data from COM PORT C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10020112/receive-nmea0183-data-from-com-port-c)

If you find a solution, please post it. It would be interesting to see it :)

Comment: Hi @aphex, thanks to you for helping. I've just post a possible solution :)